# How do I exit out from an if-statement in a for loop?

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement, break, continue

I want the program to run the if statement for the first iteration of the for loop, and then ignore it for the rest of the iterations. How do I do that? Continue and break didn't work either and led to a wacky output. The program is meant to take the first letter of each word in a string inputted and then form a word with those letters.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class First_letter
{
    public static void main()
    {
        System.out.println("\f"); // clearing screen
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence");
        String s = sc.nextLine();
        String S = s.toUpperCase();
        String NS = "";
        char c = Character.MIN_VALUE;
        for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
        {
            if( i == 0 && Character.isLetter(S.charAt(0)))
            {
                NS = NS + S.charAt(0);
            }
            if (S.charAt(i) == ' ')
            {
                if (Character.isLetter(S.charAt(i+1)) == true)
                {
                    c = S.charAt(i);
                    NS = NS + c;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The word formed from the first letter of all the words in the sentence is "+NS);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check if `i==0`? Or do the check before the loop?

Comment: Where did you put the break that doesn't work?

Comment: @khelwood That suggestion is helpful and I have implemented it, but the program still doesn't show the full word. Only the first letter of the string.

Comment: @AddeusExMachina I add the broken break function after the statement NS = NS + S.charAt(0); Also how do you indent code in the comment like that? I don't see an indent button

Comment: Why don't you use [split](https://www.baeldung.com/java-split-string) to get all words in a sentence?

Comment: If you don't want particular code executed on every loop iteration, the performant solution is often to move it out of the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand your intent:

If you only want code to execute for the first loop iteration, there's no reason for that code to be in the loop.

```
    if (S.length() != 0 && Character.isLetter(S.charAt(0)))
    {
       NS = NS + S.charAt(0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < S.length(); i++)
    {
        if (S.charAt(i) == ' ')
        {
            if (Character.isLetter(S.charAt(i+1)) == true)
            {
                c = S.charAt(i);
                NS = NS + c;
            }
        }
    }
```

Note length check before accessing the 0'the character.

For clarity, the two 'ifs' inside the loop can be combined into one, using the '&&' logical operator, but I left that part unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your questions correctly, you want to create a WORD from the first letter of every word in the sentence.
If this is true then the following should solve it. Let's keep it simple.

1. Split the sentences into words.
2. Take the first char from every word.
3. Change it to upper case.
4. And finally, join the result of every word.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("\f"); // clearing screen
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a sentence: ");
        System.out.println("The word formed from the first letter of all the words in the sentence is "
                + Joiner.on("")
                .join(Arrays.stream(sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"))
                        .filter(StringUtils::isNotBlank)
                        .map(w -> w.charAt(0))
                        .map(Character::toUpperCase).toList()
                )
        );
}
```